# how to select multiple names in a single query

Tags: sql

I have a sql query which is like that

```
 select * 
 from users 
 where uname="ali" and uname="veli"
```

but it is not worked what ı want to do is get the person whose name is "ali" and "veli" but if "ali"  is not exist and "veli" is exist, the existed ones should be return. 
How can I do this. it is easy query but I am confusing.

Comment: where something="something" or something="othersomething"?

Comment: uname can't be "ali" and "veli" at the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
select * from users where uname in ("ali", "veli")
```

As per:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM users 
 WHERE uname IN ("ali", "veli")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use OR clause or IN clause in you sql.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='ali' OR uname='veli'
```

(or)

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname IN ('ali','veli');
```

Answer (score 3):

name cannot be both ali and veli at the same time. What you want to do is to get users where name is either ali or veli, the query would look like this:

```
select * from users where (uname="ali" or uname="veli")
```

Comment: select * from users where age = 12 and (uname="ali" or uname="veli") is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need both the condition to be satisfied then use:
`select * from users where uname="ali" and uname="veli"`

If you want records where *either* condition is satisfied use:
`select * from users where uname="ali" or uname="veli"`

Hope you got it..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provided the proper logic for the where clause. Currently you are asking for the record where the entry uname is both 'ali' and 'veli' as each row will only have one entry for uname this will return nothing. The proper logic for this query is 'OR' as it tells your SQL engine to find all row where uname = 'ali' OR 'veli'. Your query will end up looking like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='ali' OR uname='veli';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select *from users where uname = 'ali'
  union
  select *from users where uname = 'veli'
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.